# Django Like Admin Project for C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, django-admin

I've been using Django recently and I really love its built-in admin interface. I was wondering if there were any C# MVC projects our there which mimicked the django admin in terms of its ease and structure?

(I'm not looking for to use the whole django model in MVC, just looking for the admin portion of it)

With enough time and customizing of the EditorTemplates & DisplayTemplates I could create something similar on a per-site basis using  `Html.DisplayForModel()` and `Html.EditorForModel()` but not all of it would be re-usable, nor have I gotten around to doing something like that (though I may go that route) and it takes a lot longer to setup. My experience with Django admin.py is that 10-15 lines of code goes a long long *long* way.

I have previously used [EntitySpaces](http://www.entityspaces.net/) and they offered a web-admin grid, but a) its web-forms, b) it got less and less support as they continued development with it and c) you can't really use it and LINQtoSQL at the same time, and I find L2S to require much less overhead.

Any recommendations or projects you know of out there?

Thanks!

Comment: You can create the Dynamic Data Site in Visual Studio 2010, which does the same thing like Django-admin site. It requires Entity Framework.

Comment: check out dynamicmvc.com and http://admin.ilaro.net/

Answer (score 3):

You can create the Dynamic Data Site in Visual Studio 2010, which does the same thing like Django-admin site. It requires Entity Framework.

Comment: Thanks! While not as exceptional as Django Admin, this seems to do the job pretty nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [sharp architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/), it automatically sets up admin CRUD for the entities you define. (However this is NHibernate based, so you wont be able to use Linq2Sql)

Though it would be great if the built-in editor templating was improved.

Comment: Sharp is cool but there is nothing really like the Django admin in .net.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen Sharp and like their approach.. but unless I'm missing something major its nothing I'm not already doing with MvcContrib and a well structured project.

Comment: @thechoyce: Sharp has a bunch of T4 templates which run when you first set up the project - you get propper admin CRUD (with edit pages for your entities right out of the box without doing anything).  Neither MvcContrib nor a well formatted project gives you that. See: http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/CastDetails/102

Comment: Watched the video.. almost exactly what I was doing a few years ago with EntitySpaces. Honestly? In the time it took me to get half way through that video I could have used `Html.EditorForModel()` to do the work for me and I wouldn't have to learn a new templating language, nor would I have to remember to re-generate templates when the entity layer changed. I totally appreciate the info, but its nothing like what the django admin.py system offers = )

Comment: There's important difference between Django Admin and T4 stuff mentioned here - Django Admin is dynamic, no code is being pregenerated. Thechoyce is right that something like pimped up 'EditorFroModel' would be the right thing.